# Many to many relationship in Power Pivot (Excel data model) - Replicate Power BI behavior in Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, many-to-many, data-modeling, powerpivot

In power BI, I can use a calendar with LTM (last 12 months) and link it to a fact table (Sales for example). There are multiple transactions in the Sales table on the same date (to multiple customers) and there are multiple Periods linked to the same date (e.g. LTM and FY2022).

[image: Calendar]

[image: Sales]

The relationship is many to many and it's perfectly managed with power BI

[image: PBI DM]

[image: Simple PBI table]

Note the total is different than the sum of the single rows (correctly)

I would like to replicate the same in Power Pivot, but I can't find a good solution.

[image: Power Pivot Error message]

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the many-to-many by using a proper date table.

In Power Pivot add a new date table, and add columns for FiscalYear, and IsLastTwelveMonths, with DAX calculated columns.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I believe this is not solving my issue. The goal is to have the different periods (FY2018, FY2019...) and LTM in the same dimension, otherwise I can't replicate the table built in Power BI. I think the real solution here is to create a new Member "LTM" using MDX and add it to the original Period field. But, again, I can't find a way in Power Pivot.Am I missing anything?